# Is it possible to detect open file dialogs on Firefox with windowMediator XUL object?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm writing a Firefox extension. Is it possible to iterate over all open windows, and detect any upload file dialog? So far I coded something like this:

var windowMediator = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
                var childWindows = windowMediator.getZOrderXULWindowEnumerator(null, true);
                while (childWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
                    var win = childWindows.getNext();
                    /*** if(win.isFileDialog) console.log('file dialog opened!'); ***/
                }

Thanks,
Eli